# Sticky Title and Button in a Modal

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox to create a modal.

Here is the [JsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/53dvyats/2/) example

I have two questions.

1. I wanted to load a modal on page load so i have used the following
   method

   ```
     $("#ModalPopup").fancybox({
        }).trigger('click');   
      });
   ```

   Is this fine or any better way to do it?
2. I have Title at the top of the modal and a Button at the end of the
   page. So when we scroll then Title and Button should be sticky

   ```
   <div id="ModalPopup">
       <h1>Title</h1>
    ......
    .......
       <div >
           <button type="button" class="btn-primary">Click</button>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   How can I make Title and Button sticky?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks does it work fine for mobile and ipad or other responsive devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrapped the body content of bodal and given the fixed height.
For Modal Opening you can use below Approach

```
$.fancybox.open($("#ModalPopup")[0]);
```

ref: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage

Please check the below link.
http://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/g34sdc2k/11/

if you use

```
  $("#ModalPopup").fancybox({
         }).trigger('click');   
       });
```

Then it will make problem, if your website is tracking the number of click event on particular element. So I will suggest not use trigger event here.

Comment: thanks does it work fine for mobile and ipad or other responsive devices

Comment: For media deceive you will have to handle height as per the media query from css. JS will will work for all

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to assign a `height` to the scrollable element that you have set in the middle of your title and button. This way, you can use `overflow-y: scroll` so that the overflowing content can become scrollable and your title and button remains at the top and bottom respectively.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27chr463/

Comment: thanks does it work fine for mobile and ipad or other responsive devices

Comment: @OwaisAhmed yes it does